# Basic PHP code snippets in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, code-completion

Is there a way to import all Sublime Text code snippets into PhpStorm?

Everything from `switch` expanding on Tab press to:

```
switch (variable) {
case 'value':
    # code...
    break;

default:
    # code...
    break;
```

}

I know you can add them manually with Live Templates but doing all of that would be an awful lot of work.

In Sublime it works along with code completion, if I start typing first 2 letters of `class` and code completion dialog pop-up on Tab key press it will expand to full class block with intelligent cursor positioning and I can press Tab again to switch from doc block to class name.

Comment: I mean [exactly that](http://gfycat.com/QualifiedAgedAlligatorsnappingturtle)